# Как заблокировать одну таблицу для чтения и записи MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть один скрипт. Несколько раз он запускается, часто несколько экземпляров скрипта выполняются одновременно. Нужно чтобы скрипт брал строку, у которой in_use=0, ставил ей in_use=1, обрабатывал и ставил обратно in_use=0. Естественно что никакой другой экземпляр скрипта не должен получить одну и туже строку. То есть чтобы не получилось что одна и та же строка обрабатывается одновременно

Задача:

1. Заблокировать таблицу чтобы никто не мог из неё читать и писать в неё, вообще
2. Выбрать строку из этой таблицы, и задать этой строке поле in_use=1, поставить флаг блокировки
3. Снять блокировку

Пробовал делать блокировку WRITE, но другие потоки могут читать таблицу. Делал блокировку READ, тогда не могу писать в таблицу. Как сделать одновременно - не знаю.

PS Есть таблица например задач. Каждый экземпляр скрипта должен взять свободную задачу, пометить что он её взял, обработать, и снять все блокировки. И в момент когда скрипт берет задачу, никакой другой не должен его опередить. То есть в момент SELECT'a надо чтобы другие процессы ждали UNLOCK TABLES

```
    $pdo->exec('LOCK TABLES links WRITE');

    $sql = "
        SELECT hash FROM links
        WHERE
          in_use!=1 AND 
          site=:site AND
          (
            parsed is null OR 
            DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),parsed)>=:revisit
          )              
        LIMIT 1
        FOR UPDATE
    ";

    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(
        [
            ':site'    => $site['name'],
            ':revisit' => static::$revisit,
        ]
    );

    if ($statement instanceof PDOStatement && $statement->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        $hash = $statement->fetchAll();
        $hash = $hash[0]['hash'];
        $pdo->exec("UPDATE links set in_use=1 where hash='" . $hash . "'");
    }
    else
    {
        $hash = false;
    }

    $pdo->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');

    return $hash;
```

Код читает из таблицы примари кей, ставит строке in_use=1. В другом методе идет обработка и после этого ставится in_use=0

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, вашу текущую задачу. Скорее всего, ее можно решить через оптимистичную блокировку меньшими затратами.

Comment: Обновил вопрос...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих копаний, решение оказалось простым. Чтобы обеспечить нужные блокировки и атомарность - достаточно было делать запросы в транзакции:

1. Делаем `SELECT hash ... WHERE in_use=0 ... FOR UPDATE` блокируем строки на запись и чтение
2. `fetchAll()` - получаем данные в php (теперь у нас есть $hash)
3. Если данные есть, то делаем `UPDATE ... SET in_use=1 ... WHERE hash=:hash` (Здесь подставляем наш $hash)
4. `commit()` транзакции

Answer (score 2):

Я давно не работал с SQL и могу ошибаться, но в целом задача выглядит так:

1. (Опционально) Выполняющийся процесс читает значение в таблице. Если он видит, что `in_use == 1`, он сразу преращает работу.
2. Процесс выполняет запрос `UPDATE <table> SET in_use = true WHERE id = <id> AND in_use = false`. Здесь, возможно, надо сделать уточнения по ISOLATION LEVEL, но, насколько понимаю, два процесса не могут обновить одну и ту же запись при любом уровне изоляции (оправьте, если это не так).
3. Процесс анализирует количество обновленных строк. 1 - блокировка успешно захвачена, 0 - кто-то успел раньше.
4. Процесс аналогичным образом снимает блокировку (лучше, если он также использует запрос с условием `in_use = true`, чтобы не снять чужую блокировку, если вдруг по каким-то причинам блок был снят вручную; также можно добавить поле owner, в которое писать случайную строку, чтобы процесс мог снять только свой блок).

В идеале сюда нужно добавить еще и некоторую дату, которая позволит перехватывать блокировку умершего процесса (спустя рационально большое время, например, сутки), чтобы избежать неприятных случаев бесконечной блокировки.

Можете посмотреть [идеальный кейс](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/consensus-on-cassandra) реализации такой блокировки на кассандре, упомянутый таймстамп там превращается во время жизни записи.

Comment: Завершаться есть in_use=1 будет в данном случае нелогично. Поясню мою задачу. Есть таблица например задач. Каждый экземпляр скрипта должен взять свободную задачу, пометить что он её взял, обработать, и снять все блокировки. И в момент когда скрипт берет задачу, никакой другой не должен его опередить

Comment: @s4urp8n он и не может опередить в моем предложении, тот, кто опередил получает количество обновленных строк = 1, любой другой получает количество обновленных строк = 0.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @s4urp8n Объедините SELECT и UPDATE в один запрос, это исключит ситуацию, когда в промежуток между SELECT и UPDATE другой запрос выполнит тот же SELECT. Все, проблемы больше нет. :)

Comment: @Yaant если вы имеет в виду отправить два запроса подряд в одном пакете, то вряд ли описываемые вами гарантии существуют.

Comment: @Etki Нет, я имею в виду запрос вида `UPDATE ... WHERE hash IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: @Yaant тоже не уверен, что это атомарно (и тем более непонятно, чем это лучше вышеприведенного примера).

Comment: @Etki по-моему, должно быть атомарно. В худшем случае может случиться дедлок, но, кажется, для задачи автора это не критично.
И я не говорю, что этот вариант лучше, это по сути чуть иная реализация того же самого, поэтому и написал комментарием, а не отдельным ответом. :) Просто исходя из приведенного автором вопроса кода, модифицировать этот код под данный вариант может оказаться немного проще. :)

Comment: дело в том. что мне нужно самому узнать hash, чтобы передать его другому методу. Насколько я знаю, отсюда UPDATE ... WHERE hash IN (SELECT ...) его не получить

Comment: @Yaant я не уверен, что MySQL предоставляет гарантии, что между SELECT и UPDATE не может быть других запросов.

Comment: @s4urp8n читайте его обычным селектом перед апдейтом. Апдейт прошел - значит, лок взят, не прошел - значит, кто-то раньше успел.

Comment: @Etki не, это же не пара отдельных операторов, это один UPDATE, просто такой вот хитрый. Он просто обязан быть атомарным. :)

Comment: @Yaant в этой области нет месту "обязан", здесь есть только сухие математические доказательства. это *не* один апдейт, это апдейт, который сопоставляет строки со вторым результатом, который имеет право оказаться устаревшим.

Comment: @Etki Если MySQL is ACID-compliant, а вроде бы утверждается, что это так, то нет, не имеет он такого права. :)

Comment: @Yaant да, я отвык от SQL, при уровне serializable (и, возможно, ниже) две транзакции просто физически не смогут существовать одновременно. Но про ACID у них даже в мануале написано, что они его "стараются придерживаться в InnoDB".